# Restoring web reference in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, visual-sourcesafe

I had a web reference set in my VS2008 ASP.NET project, but due to some source control weirdness it is no longer listed in the project.

I have the set of files in the Web References folder under my project. There's a .wsdl, .disco and several .datasource files.

Is there any way to re-add this web reference through the existing files rather than using the "Add Web Reference" dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved now.

The project file had all the references in the source control version, but the source control insisted the local file matched the server version.
Digging through the file's history showed that my local version didn't match and an update resolved it.

I think Source Safe needs the repair utility running on it.